# Use PyQtGraph by using QtDesigner

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5

I want to create and display a graph on `Main Window` which I designed in `QtDesigner`. These plot graph values are taken from `table widget`, it is not problem. Main problem is here, what I use to show the graph on `Main Window`. When I click the `"Çiz" button` I want to give the plot values and show the graphic. My Main Window is here:

[image]

`"Hacim"` and `"Yüzey Alanı (m2)"` headers are the columns for values to graph. Above the `"Çiz" Button`, there is a gap to show the graph.

**EDIT**

I look every topics about the issue but I can not handle it. I try to use it but it gives me the error. The code is:

```
    self.layoutw = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self._dlg.widget.setLayout(self.layoutw)
    self.addPlotWidget()

def addPlotWidget(self):
    x = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=2, size=10)

    widget = pg.PlotWidget(title="Some pasaasa")
    widget.plotItem.plot(x)
    self.layoutw.addWidget(widget)
```

`self._dlg.widget` is here `QWidget` that I added from QtDesigner.

When it runs, gives me a plot like that:
[image]

When I move the cursor on the plot or something else - I can nor realize it clearly - it gives me this error or other one:

[image]:

[image]

Comment: What's this _mouseMoveEvent_ ? Some functionnalities you wrote or is it a default python signal linked with PyQtGraph ?